# How do I give away Duchies?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Just picked up CK2 and trying to figure out how to survive.  I started with the Stamford Bridge scenario as William.  I've won the war and taken England, but of course my English vassals hate me.  I want to start giving away Duchies to my loyal Norman buddies, but can't figure out how.  I've revoked a number of Dukes holdings, but can't give those holdings away.  I managed to give one away via the personal diplomacy tab, but now it won't give me that option anymore.  It says I have no holdings to give away, but yet opinions scores say I am still taking a penalty for having too many duchies.  Ideas?

Comment: I thought you just passed them on the left hand side.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Is that a reference to some kind of [Europan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europa_(moon)) slang? :)

Answer (score 5):

This confused me too. It's what happens when a modern person like us cluelessly runs smack into the intricacies of the feudal system. ;)

A holding is a county seat. You have to have a county title to go with the ducal title or you can't give the duchy to that person, since they would have no land in the duchy.

Thus, you not only have to revoke the duchies, you *also* need to find a county title somewhere in order for there to be a castle, town, or bishopric to give away for the future duke to have as their ducal capital. I prefer to make this a county within the *de jure* duchy unless I am deliberately trying to change the ducal borders (since they may want *both* the duchies and that can cause trouble if you're unprepared), but it can be any county title at all to satisfy the requirement that a duke also have at least one county.

Comment: The county does not need to be within the de jure duchy.

Comment: @Aaron No, you're right, I'll fix that. I do tend to keep that arrangement since it prevents superdukes and opinion modifier problems, but it's not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you are not checking the "lower titles" option?  When checking this often times I am provided more options.

Answer (score 0):

Below are suggestions of what could be wrong.

1. You cannot give a duke title to someone unless the recipient already has at least one count title.
2. You might not have any duke titles. Does the penalty specifically refer to **duchies**?
3. It could be a bug.